# MySQL: Changing foreign key column - but keep data references intact

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a problem concerning the changing of foreign key reference and keeping data references intact.

I have one table containing comments, these comments are created by users, the users are stored in a seperate table and are referenced from the comments table by a foreign key. So i already have a lot of data in my database, that i can't just discard.

At first i had made my own login system with a unique ID for each user (their userName - i know, past me was a douche and didn't use integers for IDs), which was the ID referenced, and now I have changed it so that all users need Facebook to use the page. This is where my problem lies - i want the comments foreign key changed to the Facebook ID instead of the userName, but i don't want to loose data relation between comments and users.

I have the following setup of tables and their columns:

```
CommentsTable: [commentID] [comment] [UsersTable_userName]

UsersTable: [userID] [(varchar) userName] [(int) facebookID]
```

What i want is this instead:

```
CommentsTable: [commentID] [comment] [UsersTable_facebookID]

UsersTable: [userID] [(varchar) userName] [(int) facebookID]
```

I tried creating an additional foreign key in the commentsTable - but that didn't keep the relations.

I also can't directly change the pointer in commentsTable to point at the FacebookID since one is varchar and the other is an int.

Anyone who has experience with this who can help out or give pointers?

Comment: *"i want the comments foreign key changed to the Facebook ID"* Why?

Comment: One thing is that the userName isn't a good thing to have as my foreign key (As far as i have learned), the other is that i want to be able to set their Facebook profile picture next to a comment and if I got the Facebook ID in the comments table i don't need to make any joins or extra queries for it, since it would be in the "getComment" query. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround:
Using http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

```
UPDATE `Table A`,`Table B`
SET `Table A`.`text`=concat_ws('',`Table A`.`text`,`Table B`.`B-num`," from ",`Table B`.`date`,'/')
WHERE `Table A`.`A-num` = `Table B`.`A-num`
```

So i made a column for the Facebook ID in my comments table, used the UPDATE query shown above (Put in the correct names of course).

Afterwards I deleted my old [UsersTable_userName] column in the commentsTable and made my queries point to the FacebookID column instead.